# Application builds successfully but there is no output

Tags: java

I am continuing to study from the e-book "An introduction to Java Programming". In that e-book, I use this method:

```
/**
 * This method scans the array of cards in a for loop.
 */
public void getDetialsOfCards() {
    // Declare a local variable.
    MembershipCard card = null;

    // note the use of the instanceof operator
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfCards; i++) {
        if (cards[i] instanceof DvdMembershipCard) {
            card = cards[i];
            System.out.println("This is a DVD card with " + getNoOnLoan()
                    + " DVDs currently on loan.");

        } else if (cards[i] instanceof GameMembershipCard) {

            card = cards[i];
            System.out.println("This is a games card with " +
                    getNoOnLoan() + " CDs currently on loan");

        } else {
            System.out.println("Neither type of card.");

        }
    } // End of for loop.

}
```

Here is my main method:

```
public class CompundIfElsegetDetialsOfCards {

    // private static int noOfCards = 2;
    private static int NoOnLoan;
    private static Object[] cards;

    private static DvdMembershipCard[] dvd = new DvdMembershipCard[6];
    private static GameMembershipCard[] game = new GameMembershipCard[6];
    private static MembershipCard card;

    public static void getDetialsOfCards() {
        // Declare a local variable.

        int noOfCards = 6;

        // note the use of the instanceof operator
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfCards; i++) {
            if (cards[i] instanceof DvdMembershipCard) {
                card.equals(cards[i]);

                System.out.println("This is a DVD card with " + getNoOnLoan()
                        + " DVDs currently on loan.");

            } else if (cards[i] instanceof GameMembershipCard) {
                card.equals(cards[i]);

                System.out.println("This is a games card with " +
                        getNoOnLoan() + " CDs currently on loan");

            } else {
                System.out.println("Neither type of card.");

            }

        } // End of for loop.

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompundIfElsegetDetialsOfCards.getDetialsOfCards();
    }

    private static int getNoOnLoan() {

        System.out.println("jumlah Loan ");
        return NoOnLoan;
    }

    private static class MembershipCard {

        public MembershipCard() {

        }
    }

    private int i;

    private static class DvdMembershipCard {
        public DvdMembershipCard() {

        }
    }

    private static class GameMembershipCard {
        public GameMembershipCard() {

        }
    }
}
```

The code compiles successfully but there is no output. What I must add to solve this?

Comment: It compiled...did you run it?

Comment: I find that hard to believe, because you have at least one guaranteed `System.out.println` when your method is called from `main`.  Remember - `javac` compiles the class, `java` runs it.

Comment: i'm sorry for my english , i mean i want output from method getDetialsOfCards()

Comment: @user1895129 , then update your question with that

Comment: Are you using a IDE? I know of some problem of console in eclipse. You might need to tweak the settings. It might be the same.

Comment: I'm looking right at your `main` method.  I see your call to your static method.  There will be output from it.  Well...if you can get past some of the nasty NullPointerExceptions you'll get later on, it'll run swimmingly...

Comment: yeah , thanks makoto , mtk , Sahib... from @Jayamohan answer i got some hint to solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are not receiving any exceptions.

You will receive `java.lang.NullPointerException` in the below line

```
if (cards[i] instanceof DvdMembershipCard)
```

You have not assigned any object to `static Object[] cards;` parameter you will receive the Null pointer exception.

Comment: i got output when i change  private static Object[] cards; to private static Object[] cards = new Object[5];

Answer (score 1):

You never fill the array, with elements. No `instanceof` matches `null`... it will simply skip that whole code (w/o any exception).

Another flaw of your code (in the second block) you call `card.equals(cards[i])` instead if `card = cards[i]`, no new value is assigned.